# How to release memory from QByteArray and QByte Stream in QT

Tags: c++, qt, memory

I want to know how can i relase QByteArray and QByteStream from QT specialy at this snippet code:

```
  QByteArray DicResourceByteArray;
  QDataStream out(&DicResourceByteArray, QIODevice::WriteOnly);

  QString encoded;
  out.writeRawData(DicBlock.data + pos, DicBlock.length - pos);


  encoded = QString(DicResourceByteArray.toBase64());
```

Answer (score 5):

All will be released automatically as soon as will run out of scope according to [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization) concept. If you want to release memory explicitly, call something like `clear()` but that is unneeded - all cleaning will be done in `QByteArray`'s destructor. With QDataStream situation is the same... Also note that this is strongly preferrable coding style - when you will create your own classes try to do the same. It saves a lot of headache with managing C-like pointers.

Comment: Also, as an addition to your previous question - QString uses shared data storage. It means that multiple strings with the same data will occupy only one memory block instead of many. So, if your memory usage is still big after deleting the string - that means that there is another string pointing that data. You need to destroy all objects referencing string data for memory to be released.

Comment: @Eagle Eye: You shouldn't, because the data is still needed.

Comment: In Line :   encoded = QString(DicResourceByteArray.toBase64());
It's get 60MB after execution

Comment: no, here is the example of data sharing, no memory overhead.
At first, string data is created. Then data pointer goes to second string, third, temporary string is being destroyed. So we have only one instance of data all time.

Comment: This class create my Dictionary DB, and when create DB, it's should release memory, but it doesn't.  It's growth memory and never release memory, I've been call delete for main class that create DB, but still doesn't release memory, please help me

Comment: Also keep in mind that memory is being reserved-released with large blocks, which are used internally with new, constructors and so on. (this is for fast work) Actually such block would never be released until it has some valid data inside. This may cause your program to consume much more memory then it need.

Comment: @Eagle Eye : According to http://en.kioskea.net/contents/base/base64.php3 base64 encoding is responsible for an overall 33% increase in the volume of all encoded data. So in general you will use more memory to store base64 encoded data than to store binary data.

Comment: @OrcunC: I know that, i want to release memory after store data in DB

Answer (score 2):

The memory held by a QByteArray is automatically freed when the object goes out of scope.
the QDataStream just is just a way to access the QByteArray, so it does not have data on is own (it can use some buffers for internal purposes but you don't have to manage them) 
You can use clear() to clear the QByteArray content.
You can also use reserve() and resize() to tune the memory usage, but you should not need them most of the time.